# Which of the following statements are true? topic of lines and planes

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vectors

> 1. if line $l$ is the intersection line of two planes $x+y+z=3$ and $x-y+2=0$ then the vector $\vec a =(1,1,2)$ is parallel to the line $l$
> 2. the equation of the line passing through two points $M_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $M_2=(x_2,y_2,z_3)$ is $x=x_1+(x_2-x_1)\cdot t$ , $y=y_1+(y_2-y_1)\cdot t$ , $z=z_1+(z_2-z_1)\cdot t$
> 3. if the vector $\vec s$ is a direction vector of the line $l$ , then for every $\alpha \Bbb R$ the vector $\alpha \vec s$ is also a direction vector of $l$
> 4. if the line $l$ is $\frac{x-2}{5}=\frac{y+1}{3}=\frac{z}{2}$ then the point $M=(7,2,-3)$ is on the line
> 5. if the line $l$ is $\frac{x+3}{5}=\frac{1-y}{2}=\frac{z-2}{3}$ then the vector $\vec a=(5,2,3)$ is the direction vector of the line

---

First statement is not correct because $\vec n_1=(1,1,1)$ and $\vec n_2=(1,-1,0)$ and from the normals we can get the direction vector of the line from cross product $\vec n_1 \times \vec n_2 = (1,1,-2)$ and solving the planes equations we get a point $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{2}, 0)$ so the line equation is $l= (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{2}, 0) +t \cdot (1,1,-2)$ now to check if the direction vector is parallel to the given vector we get $(1,1,-2) \not = t(1,1,-2)$.

Second statement I believe is true because $\vec M_1M_2=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)$ so $l=(x_1,y_1,z_1)+t(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)$

Third statement
Not true what if $\alpha = 0$?

Fourth statement also not true because given $x=5t+2$,$y=2t-1$ ,$z=2t$ and $M=(7,2,-3)$ we get different $t$ values

Fifth statement is not true because the direction vector is $\vec s = (5,-2,3)$ not $\vec s = (5,2,3)$

Thank you for any tips and help

Comment: What help do you want?

Comment: @insipidintegrator if my solution and ways are correct? or if there are any other better ways to approach

Comment: 1. you can use cross product only if $\Bbb R^3 $ is equipped with the canonical inner product.  $\Bbb R^3$ can be "leaned".

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Thank you , are the others solutions ok? is the second statement really true or did I get it wrong?

Comment: I'm ok with what you say about the second statement : you can even write $\vec{M_1M_2}=M_2-M_1$ in affine space $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: 2. this is called a parametric equation of $(M_1M_2)$ and apart from other precisions of the statement, it is an equation. Maybe precise "an" instead of "the".